# Why did Han own a training remote?

Tags: star-wars, droids, a-new-hope, jedi-training

In *Star Wars - Episode IV: A New Hope*, Luke uses a training remote found onboard the Millennium Falcon as part of his lightsaber training.  A picture on the [Wookieepedia page for "Training Remotes"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Training_remote) is captioned "Han Solo's training remote":

[image: Training Remote floating]
*"Han Solo's Training Remote"*

The remote remained aboard the ship for decades afterwards, and was discovered much later by Finn in *The Force Awakens*, while he is rooting around in equipment boxes.

I don't understand why a non-Force-user would have one of these devices around - it seems to be designed for use by Jedi learning to deflect blasters, and appears to have very little usefulness to anyone else.

### Why does Han Solo own a training remote?

Comment: Yeah! Why *would* Han need a remote?!

Comment: How do we know it's *his*? Could have been Old Ben's, or just one of the pieces of cargo on the MF, or just came with the ship?

Comment: Yeah, I always assumed Old Ben brought it along with him.

Comment: For the sake of reference, multiple sources now confirm that the remote was indeed the property of Han Solo, and was kept aboard the Falcon by Solo for training purposes.

Comment: It's so that when he trains he doesn't shoot first. Han didn't shoot first.

Comment: @Oak - GET.  OUT.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Han's training remote is used for target practice and to allow him to practice his "[quick-draw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHH6YVHGh90&feature=youtu.be&t=7s)"

> Luke stepped back to the center of the hold, activated his lightsaber,
>   and returned his attention to the hovering remote. **Ben had rightly
>   assumed that Han kept a remote on board for quick-draw target
>   practice,** and had programmed the device to fire harmless sting bursts
>   for Luke to deflect with his lightsaber. Luke kept his eyes on the
>   remote and batted at two fired bursts as Han Solo entered the hold. - <sub><sup>**[SW: A New Hope - Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization))**</sup></sub>

[image: Training Remote]
Image from [**Star Wars: The Visual Dictionary**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Dictionary)

and from [The Weapon of a Jedi: A Luke Skywalker Adventure](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Weapon_of_a_Jedi:_A_Luke_Skywalker_Adventure)

> *He realized his lightsaber was in his hand. And then he sensed
>   something else. **He looked up and saw three remotes hovering
>   nearby—remotes like the one Han Solo had kept for blaster target
>   practice aboard the Millennium Falcon.***
>
> *Three? He couldn’t fend off three—he had enough trouble anticipating
>   the actions of just one. But the Force was very strong there. He could
>   feel it all around him, a living thing, like wind or rain.*

Comment: It is also confirmed in *Journey to Star Wars:  The Force Awakens - The Weapon of a  Jedi:  A Luke Skywalker Adventure*.  Luke has a dream about himself using remotes, and he describes them as "like the one Han kept for blaster practice" or something to that effect.

Comment: "remotes like the one Han Solo had kept for blaster target practice aboard the Millennium Falcon."

Comment: @WadCheber - Good find. Nicely backs up the novelisation

Comment: You just took my pseudo-answer, added a bunch of legitimate sources to it, and turned it into a solid answer instead of groundless speculation. ;)  Well done!

Comment: @user45623 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM

Comment: But if Han misses a practice shot, he just blew a hole in the wall of his ship...

Comment: @JoshB - He never misses